# "search files by name" can't find .env(dotenv) files in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Definitely, there are `.env*` files in workspace of VS Code. But can't find any `.env*` files using "search files by name" (the palette when press `cmd`+`p` or `ctrl`+`p`)

I tried,

1. restart VS code several times.
2. update VS code to version 1.71.1(newest version)
3. empty workspace settings file located at `./.vscode/settings.json`

[files in workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbGpX.png)

[no matching results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsdgh.png)

[vscode version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN2cy.png)

Any clue?

Comment: create an issue at the VSC repo

Comment: Is your `.env` symlinked? Mine is and can't be found by searching, although I could locate it in the Explorer

Comment: @bilogic No, it is not. Just plain `.env` file at the project root.

Comment: I had opened an issue at the vsc repo

Comment: I and many other people I work with have had this same issue and so far nobody has come up with an answer for why it happens. It's not listed in Files: Exclude. All I can say is they do come up if I type cmt+t then "."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Holy heck I finally found it: open settings and look for "use ignore files".

[image]

Comment: You're going to want to pair this with updates to the "Search: Exclude" setting to make sure you're not getting back search results in things like node_modules, .cache, .next, .npm, /dist, /build etc